# How to display Posts on Wordpress home page, Order by last updated

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I want to display Posts order by Last updated on the home page, how to right function for it and where to paste that function in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Create your plugin and paste this function in plugin file.

```
function wpb_lastupdated_posts() 
{ 
    // Query Arguments
    $lastupdated_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'modified',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
    );
    //Loop to display 5 recently updated posts
    $lastupdated_loop = new WP_Query( $lastupdated_args );
    $counter = 1;
    $string .= '<ul>';
    while( $lastupdated_loop->have_posts() && $counter < 5 ) : $lastupdated_loop->the_post();
    $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $lastupdated_loop->post->ID ) . '"> ' .get_the_title( $lastupdated_loop->post->ID ) . '</a> ( '. get_the_modified_date() .') </li>';
    $counter++;
    endwhile; 
    $string .= '</ul>';
    return $string;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
} 
//add a shortcode
add_shortcode('lastupdated-posts', 'wpb_lastupdated_posts');

use this shortcode : [lastupdated-posts]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to do this

1. add this code in the functions.php file

   ```
   function shortcode_latest_homepage_posts(){

   $lquery = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'DESC'));

   if($lquery->have_posts()){
      while($lquery->have_posts()){
        $lquery->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }

   } 

   wp_reset_postdata();

   }

   add_shortcode('latest_posts', 'shortcode_latest_homepage_posts');
   ```

and add simply this [latest_posts] shortcode in the page editor that you have assign for the front page in cms

OR

2. add this code in functions.php

   ```
   function latest_homepage_posts(){

   $lquery = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'DESC'));

   if($lquery->have_posts()){
     while($lquery->have_posts()){
       $lquery->the_post();
         the_title();
         the_content();
     }

   } 

   wp_reset_postdata();

   }

   add_action('latest_post', 'latest_homepage_posts');
   ```

and add this code at the place where you want to show the post in the template that assign for or made for a home page like home.php or front-page.php

```
 <?php do_action('latest_post');?>
```

OR
3. simply add this code at the place where you want to show the post in the template that assign for or made for a home page like home.php or front-page.php

```
<?php 


    $lquery = new WP_Query(array('order' => 'DESC'));

    if($lquery->have_posts()){
       while($lquery->have_posts()){
          $lquery->the_post();
          the_title();
          the_content();
      }

  } 

  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```